# Filtering a table based on a non-unique column to give only unique fields in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How would I filter out a table that it only includes one value for a column (it does not matter which one).

The SQL query used to create the below looks like this :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        S.Id AS ReferenceID,
        M.NewModuleID AS ModuleId,
        SM.Compulsory           
    FROM
        Struct S
    INNER JOIN
        StructModule SM 
             ON SM.StructId = S.Id
    INNER JOIN
        ModuleMap M 
             ON M.StructId = S.Id 
             AND SM.ModuleId = M.OldModuleId
```

However this does not return the values in the way that I need it. the return table looks like this:

```
ReferenceID  NewModuleID  Compulsory
     1            100          1
     1            210          0
     2            251          1
     2            251          0
```

However I would like the SQL query to return a unique value for the NewModuleID field. Ideally taking the first occurrence of a value

the relevant columns of the above tables are as follows:

```
Struct:
      ID          (INT)

StructModule:
      ID          (INT)
      StructID    (INT)
      ModuleID    (INT)
      Compulsory  (BIT)

 ModuleMap:
      ID          (INT)
      OldModuleId (INT)
      StructID    (INT)
      NewModuleID (INT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but after reading following statement.

> However I would like the SQL query to return a unique value for the
>   NewModuleID field. Ideally taking the first occurrence of a value

I can guess that you are looking for something like following query.

```
   SELECT * FROM
   (
    SELECT 
        S.Id AS ReferenceID,
        M.NewModuleID AS ModuleId,
        SM.Compulsory     ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY S.ID, M.NewModuleID ORDER BY   M.NewModuleID) RN    
    FROM
        Struct S
    INNER JOIN
        StructModule SM 
             ON SM.StructId = S.Id
    INNER JOIN
        ModuleMap M 
             ON M.StructId = S.Id 
             AND SM.ModuleId = M.OldModuleId
    )T
    WHERE RN=1
```

Note : You don't need distinct if you are using `RN=1` condition.

Comment: This worked perfectly. All I needed to do since I needed to do a union was not SELECT * but only select the fields I needed.